# Execute flask-SQLAlchemy subquery

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to execute the following subquery in flask-SQLAlchemy but don't know how:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT * 
     FROM  `articles` 
     WHERE publisher_id = "bild"
     ORDER BY date_time DESC 
     LIMIT 10
) AS t
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 2
```

I know I can build the query as:

```
subq = Article.query.filter(Article.publisher_id =='bild').order_by(Article.date_time.desc()).limit(10).subquery()
qry = subq.select().order_by(func.rand()).limit(2)
```

However I don't know how to execute it in the same fashion as I would execute e.g.

```
articles = Article.query.filter(Article.publisher_id =='bild').all()
```

i.e. to get all the Article objects. What I can do is call

```
db.session.execute(qry).fetchall()
```

but this only gives me a list with actual row values instead of the objects on which I could for example call another function (like `article.to_json()`).

Any ideas? `qry` is a `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select` object and `db.session.execute(qry)` a `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy` while `Article.query`, on which I could call `all()`, is a `flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [select_entity_from](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_entity_from)

```
qry = db.session.query(Article).select_entity_from(subq).order_by(func.rand()).limit(2)
```

or [from_self](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_self)

```
Article.query.filter(Article.publisher_id =='bild')\
             .order_by(Article.date_time.desc())\
             .limit(10)\
             .from_self()\
             .order_by(func.rand())\
             .limit(2)
```